# Is it possible to mock typescript decorator?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, mocking, decorator

Given I have method decorator, e.g.

```
class Service {
    @LogCall()
    doSomething() {
        return 1 + 1;
    }    
}
```

Is it possible to mock `@LogCall` decorator in unit tests, so it won't be applied or applied with mocked logic?

I am looking for generic solution for any typescript decorator, as it is possible to update your decorator to check `window.disableLogDecorator` flag or something to turn it off during tests, but that's not reusable solution.

---

*Our use case is, of course, much more complex than in example provided - we have `@memoizeSelector` which is applied to `ngrx/store` selectors so they're called only when specific state parts are updated. Due to way we mock state in our tests, `@memoizeSelector` breaks our tests so ideally we'd like disable it.*

Comment: Yes this is possible but you need to mock the module that exports the decorator. You can do this using your module loader provided it's sufficiently flexible. For example, SystemJS lets you do this very easily. Remember, a decorator is just a function.

Answer (score -2):

I doubt there are any mocks for decorators. You can add static switch and handle it inside of decorator or create configurable decorator factory (but still static):

```
 @LogCall(LogCallFactory)

 export function LogCall(factory:Function):Function
 {
    return function(target:Object, propertyKey:string, descriptor:TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>)
    {
       return factory(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
    }
 }
```

Decorators are written at compile time, so probably could use conditional compilation.

Comment: "Decorators are written at compile time, so probably could use conditional compilation." This statement doesn't make sense

Comment: Do you have any other arguments?

Comment: Since the language doesn't support conditional-compilation and since decorators are a syntactic sugar for function calls, this answer does not that make sense. Perhaps you're confused by the optional metadata emit that typescript can provide in addition to decorator standard decorator behavior, and therefore think they are a compile time construct. Anyway if something is imported from a module you can mock it by configuring your loader of bundler appropriately.

Comment: Conditional compilation can be achieved very easily by feeding appropriate source files to compiler or bundler, it has nothing to do with language. Decorator metadata is written at compile time and it defines both target and decorator, this is why word "written" was used. So which part of this does not make sense?

Comment: Decorators are not simply about metadata. RE Conditional compilation: you are not wrong and indeed what you wrote in your comment, "Conditional compilation can be achieved very easily by feeding appropriate source files to compiler or bundler", should be written in your answer _in place of the term itself. Many languages have built in facilities, such as pre-processor macros, for such purposes, JavaScript does not and therefore requires a loader or bundler to provide such a facility.

Comment: Downvoting since you can mock decorators by mocking the module's exports